# Pass file name param from outlook to excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

> Can I pass fileName through to the excel macro I'm calling in the
>   following Outlook routine?  Right now the saveReportstoDisk sub is being kicked off by an outlook rule, and I can get my excel file to open, I'm just now sure how to pass the fileName parameter from the two Outlook subs, to my excel sub.

```
Sub saveReportstoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dateFormat

    saveFolder = "C:\MyFolder"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        fileName = objAtt.fileName
        i = i + 1
        dateFormat = Format(Now, "YYYY-mm-dd HH_mm_ss")
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & fileName
    Next objAtt

    CallExcel

End Sub

Sub CallExcel()
    Dim excelApp As Object

    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    excelApp.Visible = True

    excelApp.Workbooks.Open "I:\ImportGenerator.xlsm"

    ' run the macro
    excelApp.Run "ThisWorkbook.PrepareReport"

    excelApp.Quit

    Set excelApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I see where you're going with this but I'm not looking to open the sFIle from there. I need to pass sFile through to my excel macro. – Tourless 29 mins ago

What you need is [How to call Microsoft Excel macros that take parameters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/153307/how-to-call-microsoft-excel-macros-that-take-parameters)

I am assuming that right now your macro looks like this in Excel

```
Sub PrepareReport()

End Sub
```

Change it to

```
Sub PrepareReport(sFile As String)
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

And then from Outlook pass the file name as

```
excelApp.Run "ThisWorkbook.PrepareReport", FileName
```

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this but I'm not looking to open the sFIle from there.  I need to pass sFile through to my excel macro.

Comment: Even that is possible :) I have answered that in the past. Let me search for the link. You macro should be able to accept a parameter

Comment: Is this what you want? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/153307/how-to-call-microsoft-excel-macros-that-take-parameters

Comment: i think so.  I have to work it through but it does look like what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let me simplify it for you in the above post. Gimme 5 mins

Comment: Does that have to be run from a workbook open event? Or does the macro have to be in the personal workbook?

Comment: No it is not necessary. The code can be in a module as well. BTW I updated my post. You may have to refresh the page to see it. Also I have not tested what I posted. If you get stuck let me know

Comment: But Outlook is passing sFile as the file name will never be the same twice.  I also notice that sFile is returning the full path to the file which I don't think is a problem but once excel launches my xlsm the macro never executes.

Comment: got it.  not sure if there is a real difference but I was able to call the macro by changing excelApp.Run "ThisWorkbook.PrepareReport", FileName to excelApp.Run "Module1.PrepareReport", FileName.